# "(#100) object URL is not properly formatted" while trying to setup facebook subscription

Tags: facebook

I am trying to setup facebook subscriptions for checkins, I have already asked for the user_checkins permission in my app, so I issue the following url

https://graph.facebook.com//subscriptions?access_token=&object=user&callback_url=&verity_token=&fields=checkin

To which I get

"(#100) object URL is not properly formatted"

The access token is valid, the url is properly encoded and points to a page according to FB guidelines about hub.xxx, everything seems normal. I am doing a GET though. Could this be the problem? Should it be a POST as the docs? Or is there another issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this request should be `POST` (or `GET` with `method=post` argument passed). And this exactly the error message returned if you fail to do so...